# Can't start the game and don't know how to add inventory

Tags: python, project, adventure

I have to make a text based game for a final project. The goal is to pick up 6 items and to move from room to room. I'm still very new at this and would like some help! I can't seem to call the functions and I don't know how to add an inventory. Here is my current code:

```
def show_instructions():
   #print a main menu and the commands
   print("Thousand Year Vampire")
   print("Collect 6 items to defeat the vampire or be destroyed by her.")
   print("Move commands: go South, go North, go East, go West")
   print("Add to Inventory: get 'item name'")


def showStatus(current_room, inventory, rooms):
    #print the player's current location
    #print the current inventory
    #print an item if there is one


def main():
    #define inventory and dictionary linking other rooms
    rooms = {

        'Entry Way': { 'North': 'Stalagmite Cavern'},
        'Stalagmite Cavern': {'North': 'Grand Cavern', 'South': 'Entry Way', 'item': 'torch'},
        'Grand Cavern': {'North': 'Hallway', 'East': 'Armory', 'West': 'Bedroom', 'South': 'Stalagmite Cavern', 'item': 'cross'},
        'Armory': {'North': 'Treasure Trove', 'West': 'Grand Cavern', 'item': 'Stake'},
        'Treasure Trove': {'South': 'Armory', 'item': 'silver'},
        'Bedroom': {'North': 'Storage', 'East': 'Grand Cavern', 'item': 'elaborate comb'},
        'Storage': {'South': 'Bedroom', 'item': 'mirror'},
        'Hallway': {'North': 'Cliff Top', 'South': 'Grand Cavern'},
        'Cliff Top': {'South': 'Hallway', 'item': 'Orla'}
    }
# setting up inventory
inventory = []

# setting the starting room
starting_room = 'Great Hall'

# set current room to starting room
current_room = starting_room

while True:
    print("\nYou are currently in {}".format(current_room))
    move = input("Enter 'go North/South/East/West' to move or 'Exit': ").split()[-1].capitalize()

    # user to exit
    if move == 'Exit':
        current_room = 'exit'
        break

    # a correct move
    elif move in rooms[current_room]:
        current_room = rooms[current_room][move]

    # incorrect move
    else:
        print("You can't go that way. There is nothing to the {}".format(move))



#loop forever

#show game instructions
show_instructions()
```

Comment: is your code aligned correctly on this page? Is main() defined within showStatus?  Why do you need a function defined as main() to initialize `rooms`. Can't you just do it as part of the beginning of the program.

Comment: Also how do you plan on moving from one room to another. Your program sets up the player to start at `Great Hall`. How does the player move from `Great Hall` to other rooms. Also, where is `Great Hall` in `rooms` dictionary?

Comment: Ah thanks for the catch! It was supposed to be entry way. How would I define the `rooms`?

Comment: just remove def main(). You dont need that to start with. Just like you have initialized variables `inventory` and `starting_room`, you can just define the dict as `rooms = {....} `

Comment: I did that but when I run the program it says: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Arzuera\PycharmProjects\TextBasedGame\main.py", line 51, in <module>
    elif move in rooms[starting_room]:
NameError: name 'rooms' is not defined

Comment: Need to fix the indentation -- indentation is important in Python!

Comment: @TheDrowningGuppy, I took the liberty of editing your code in the question section. Let me know if the indentation of your program is correctly set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the final answer but I wanted to show you the changes you can make to the code to get the program to work.

This is just restructuring your code. It is not the solution. Once we understand what the problem is, I can help add to this to solve for it.

```
def show_instructions():
   #print a main menu and the commands
   print("Thousand Year Vampire")
   print("Collect 6 items to defeat the vampire or be destroyed by her.")
   print("Move commands: go South, go North, go East, go West")
   print("Add to Inventory: get 'item name'")

def showStatus(current_room, inventory, rooms):
    #print the player's current location
    #print the current inventory
    #print an item if there is one

#define inventory and dictionary linking other rooms
rooms = {

    'Entry Way': { 'North': 'Stalagmite Cavern'},
    'Stalagmite Cavern': {'North': 'Grand Cavern', 'South': 'Entry Way', 'item': 'torch'},
    'Grand Cavern': {'North': 'Hallway', 'East': 'Armory', 'West': 'Bedroom', 'South': 'Stalagmite Cavern', 'item': 'cross'},
    'Armory': {'North': 'Treasure Trove', 'West': 'Grand Cavern', 'item': 'Stake'},
    'Treasure Trove': {'South': 'Armory', 'item': 'silver'},
    'Bedroom': {'North': 'Storage', 'East': 'Grand Cavern', 'item': 'elaborate comb'},
    'Storage': {'South': 'Bedroom', 'item': 'mirror'},
    'Hallway': {'North': 'Cliff Top', 'South': 'Grand Cavern'},
    'Cliff Top': {'South': 'Hallway', 'item': 'Orla'}
}
# setting up inventory
inventory = []

# setting the starting room
starting_room = 'Hallway'

# set current room to starting room
current_room = starting_room

#show game instructions
show_instructions()

while True:
    print("\nYou are currently in {}".format(current_room))
    move = input("Enter 'go North/South/East/West' to move or 'Exit': ").split()[-1].capitalize()

    # user to exit
    if move == 'Exit':
        current_room = 'exit'
        break

    # a correct move
    elif move in rooms[current_room]:
        current_room = rooms[current_room][move]

    # incorrect move
    else:
        print("You can't go that way. There is nothing to the {}".format(move))

#loop forever
```

Comment: it says it needs an indent though. Now when I run it, it says:  File "C:\Users\Arzuera\PycharmProjects\TextBasedGame\main.py", line 16
    rooms = {
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: I found the answer. I had to put what I wanted under showStatus. It kept treating the dictionaries as items in that function. The game works perfectly now and I can move room to room! Thank you @JoeFerndz for being patient with me. Now how would I go about adding an inventory? the goal is to collect 6 items before running into the boss. If they run into the boss without all 6 items then they lose.